# WILDFLY 28.0.0_Final - Intellij IDEA, Unable to auto launch web app archive on browser

Tags: intellij-idea, deployment, wildfly

WILDFLY 28.0.0_Final integrated with Intellij IDEA ultimate does not auto launch the web app on the web browser after build.

I have used wildfly 26.0.0_Final before with Intellij IDEA ultimate and the behavior is as follows :

1- I set up Intellij IDEA (ultimate) with wildfly 26, select a maven .war archive to deploy

2- I launch Wildfly 26 from Intellij and the result is :

3- AUTO BUILD THE WAR ARCHIVE ;

4- AUTO LAUNCH OF THE WEB APP on the web browser

5- ***I might be wrong here*** but i think the standalone.xml file is also AUTO EDITED and a new tag is added (<deployments> ... </>)

ALL GOOD TILL HERE

However, WILDFLY 28.0.0_Final **does not auto launch of the web app on the web browser after build**.

Am I missing a configuration?

Is it a normal behavior?

Comment: Does it work with a brand new installation of WildFly webserver without any customizations? If possible please share a small project sample at https://uploads.jetbrains.com/ and share the UploadID here

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and resolved it by switching Intellij IDEA to the latest version 2023.2.

Reference:
[Wildfly 28 - NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.as.controller.client.ModelControllerClient$Factory.create : IDEA-320285 (jetbrains.com)](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-320285?_ga=2.103056000.186660760.1690771371-564264119.1690771371)